# load multiple frames with content

Tags: php, jquery

now i ma working on a page which have multiple contents and every content have 1 frame. i have total 5 frames and i need to do this every product load with new frame. and when 5 frame complete then load again 1 ,2,3,4,5. but i don't understand how can i do this. below my code.

```
<?php
$allgfts=mysql_query("select id,image_url from {$statement} order by id limit {$startpoint}, {$limit}");
while($gfts=mysql_fetch_array($allgfts))
{
$id=$gfts['id'];
$image=$gfts['image_url'];
?>
       <div id="pic-1">
           <div class="thumbnail-item">
                     <?php echo '<a href="g_detail.php?id='.$id.'"><img src="images/'.$image.'" alt="" width="161" height="161" class="thumbnail g-size" /></a>'; ?>       
                        <span><?php echo '<a href="g_detail.php?id='.$id.'">Readmore</a>';?></span>
                        <?php echo '<a class="gtbtn" href="g_buy.php?id='.$id.'">Get This</a>';?>

       </div>     
        </div>  
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: no no just content list

Comment: the code seems to be correct! please show me your css styles!

Comment: do you understand my question? i want to add frames with items. means every item have frame. and total frame is 5 . wehn 5 frames complete then next item show with frame 1 no 1

Comment: what is your meaning from frame!? `every item have frames`

Comment: frame means image. look every content when load  then i need to show item in frame. means look like. i have an album which have 100 images. and 50 image have his own frame and wehn 50 frame done. in images then load again frame with image no 51 and frame no 1. do you understand ?

Answer (score 1):

at last i dont understand completely

but

i think you must do some thing like this

```
while(get your products){
echo "..........details..........";
echo "..........details..........";
echo "..........details..........";
      while(get your products images with limit of 5){
          echo "images details";
      }
}
```

maybe help...